# Replace certain characters in an input-string with pre-defined replacement characters (python 3)

Tags: python

I want to write a program that encodes a word you typed into the console like this:

If You write an A for example it will be replaced with a Z 
or you type T and get a U.

Example:

```
A --> Z  
T --> U 
H --> F
```

If it's possible can you tell me how to change the word you typed in the console?

Still need help can't figure out how to do it !

Comment: I edited the title of your question, hopefully this is a bit clearer.

Comment: So you type apple for example and you have a list that shows what letter replaces a for example z and then the console prints out zpple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's easy, just define a dictionary which maps characters to their replacement.

```
>>> replacers = {'A':'Z', 'T':'U', 'H':'F'}
>>> inp = raw_input()
A T H X
>>> ''.join(replacers.get(c, c) for c in inp)
'Z U F X'
```

I don't know where exactly you want to go and whether case-sensitivity matters, or if there's a more general rule to determine the replacement character that you did not tell us - but this should get you started.

*edit*:
an explanation was requested:

`(replacers.get(c, c) for c in inp)` is a generator which spits out the following items for the example input:

```
>>> [replacers.get(c, c) for c in inp]
['Z', ' ', 'U', ' ', 'F', ' ', 'X']
```

For each character `c` in the input string `inp` we ge the replacement character from the `replacers` dictionary, or the character itself if it cannot be found in the dictionary. The default value is the second argument passed to `replacers.get`.

Finally, `''.join(some_iterable)` builds a string from all the items of an iterable (in our case, the generator), glueing them together with the string `join` is being called on in between. Example:

```
>>> 'x'.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
'axbxc'
```

In our case, the string is empty, which has the effect of simply concatenating all the items in the iterable.

Comment: It was just an example i'm going to make a table that shows what letter replaces what letter. Actually thanks for the code :) Should help me with my plan.

Comment: I would love to hear the reason for the downvote, such that I can improve my answer.

Comment: @timgeb: I didn't down-vote, but this seems like a straightforward response to me, so +1.

Comment: I seriously don't know who downvoted.. That's the best answer i could get in the internet

Comment: Actually could you explain "''.join(replacers.get(c, c) for c in inp)" i'm new to python and for me it doesn't work properly

Comment: @Venx added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import maketrans

orginalCharacters = "aeiou"
encodedCharacters = "12345"
trantab = maketrans(orginalCharacters, encodedCharacters)

text = "this is string example";
print text.translate(trantab)
```

this will output:

```
th3s 3s str3ng 2x1mpl2
```

Look up the function **translate** for more info

Answer (score -1):

timgeb has a great solution; alternatively, you could also use what's on [this page of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) and use a `for` loop to assign a random integer to each letter, and store it in a dictionary (see `randint`).

This would be more helpful if you want it to change every time you run your program.

Comment: Please describe your solution in a way that remains clear if the page you link to were to go away.

Comment: The asker of the question requested to not post a whole code so they could do it themselves; also since I linked to the Python docs, there's no reason it should actually disappear.

Comment: The documentation is likely to remain available; that particular URL is another story.

Comment: I was unaware that the doc URLs changed frequently enough to warrant direct quoting. If that's the case, I'll come back and edit my answer.